# How to change font of current frame?

Tags: fonts

I have two displays and different frames on each. Each display has very different DPI so I need different fonts sizes for them.

How can I set different fonts sizes for different frames (font size changes not applied globally)?

Comment: Emacs faces measure the size of the font in "points" rather than pixels, so presumably it should already take DPI into account.  IOW, please `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also change  font like so :- `(set-frame-font "PragmataPro 13")`, 
where the 2nd argument is the size you want to use.

EDIT: if you are running emacsclient by connecting to an emacs daemon process, the above answer will not work. Instead put this in your `init.el`: `(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "PragmataPro-13")))`

Comment: Yes. Or `(modify-frame-parameters nil (list (cons 'font YOUR-CHOSEN-FONT)))`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the second parameter of `set-face-attribute` correspond to what frame you want the face-attribute to change so:

```
;; on my retina display (2880x1800)
(set-face-attribute 'default (selected-frame) :font "Source Code Pro" :height 140 :weight 'medium)

;; on my 4k external display (3840 x 2160)
(set-face-attribute 'default (selected-frame) :font "Source Code Pro" :height 210 :weight 'medium)
```

In this case I'm only changing the font `:height`. Anyway, I'm setting [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27910/308) as valid answer because it is the one I will be using.